# Authorization for PHP API with certificate authentication

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to access an API using PHP, for which I have the cert.pem, key.pem, and an encryption key.

I suspect that my authorization column in this code is not correct, so I keep getting an Authorization field missing, or that I do not have access to this API. But I do have the access.

Secondly, for the key.pem, should I write it as CURLOPT_CAINFO or CURLOPT_SSLKEY.

Please suggest what step is missing or incorrect in this code below.

```
$url = "API endpoint url";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
   "Accept: application/json",
   "Authorization: ",
);
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => '2',
        CURLOPT_CAINFO => 'key.pem',
        CURLOPT_SSLCERT => 'cert.pem' 
    ));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);
```

Comment: `CURLOPT_SSLKEY` for the .key ; your `Authorization: ` header is indeed empty though,  or did you just remove that in your post for privacy reasons ?

Comment: Thanks. I will change the SSLKEY. The Auth is blank because I don't know what to put for CERTIFICATE authentication. I had a client:Secret for the oAuth authentication. But for Certificate authentication, I am not sure what to write. Can you suggest?

Comment: No idea, but i imagine that's something the provider of that API will have listed in their documentation